# Conditional formatting in Excel 2013

Tags: spreadsheet, datasheet

I need to make conditional formatting in Excel.
I need to switch between 2 colors, for example white and grey.
Give one color when email fields have the same content 1 or more times, and switch to the second color when new data.

See an example here:
[Example of the desired formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LmCX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the Email field in Column A, have an additional calculated column which tells whether the Previous Row and Current Row emails are same.

The formula for the additional calculated column is given below. it will tell whether previous row and current row emails are same. if they are same, it will return TRUE, else it will return FALSE.

Then apply conditional formatting on this calculated column. TRUE means one color, FALSE means another color.

```
=EXACT(INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 1),INDIRECT("A" & ROW()))
```